# arm_navigation turtlebot considers only start&end positions

Tags: ros, turtlebot-arm, arm-navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am using the turtlebot_arm_bringup constraint_aware_simple_arm_server.launch which uses the arm_navigation stack.

**The problem**
When I add a collision object that is neither at the start or end poses of the trajectory but somewhere in the middle, the arm ignores it and simply passes through it.

**Attempts so far**
I retrieved the planning scene before and after sending the goal to the arm, and the collision object is definitely present, and in the ¨allowed_collision_matrix¨ all entries for this object are marked as False.

When I move the object´s pose to collide with the end pose (i.e. the object pose is not identical to the end goal´s pose but the shape overlaps it) the 'move_arm' server returns ¨success: False¨ as it should. The same thing happens if the object collides with the starting pose.

**Question**
What I thought the constraint_aware_simple_arm_server (or arm_kinematics_constraint_aware) is supposed to do given a goal, is calculate and execute a trajectory that will not pass through collision objects, is this wrong? Can I only get a regular (constraint-ignoring) trajectory and then check its validity?

**Background details**
ROS electric on ubuntu 11.10 (upgraded from 11.04)
Machine: Intel Core i5-2500 CPU @ 3.30GHz x 4. 32-bit.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37268/arm_navigation-turtlebot-considers-only-start&end-positions/) by [NTo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2385/nto/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2012-06-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm doing the same thing with a arm robot. When I add a object between the start pose and the end pose, it's works correctly. The arm avoids the object.
Add you the object during movement or before the trajectory calculation ?
Me, my problem is when I add a object during the movement because the trajectory is already calculated y sent. So I check the state validity to know if there is collision but it's the same problem, I think the scene is not updated. I can't see mi object in Rviz during the movement.

How it's possible to actualize the scene ?

---

Originally posted by [jep31](https://answers.ros.org/users/2564/jep31/) with karma: 411 on 2012-07-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0